# two dimensional $_SESSION in php

Tags: php, session

I'm building a server side workers manager script which saves the "jobs to work on" data in the $_SESSION and each time calls itself with the next job to be done. This gives me control, because I can stop and re-continue whenever I need. This works great. The problem I'm having is to be able to run a couple of these Managers in the same browser because they share the $_SESSION. So I'm trying to create a two-dimensional $_SESSION array that keeps different data according to the sessionId I specify in the http request. I want to do this in order to run a number of crawlers from the same browser that do one task at a time and keep a list of remaining tasks in its' `$_SESSION[$sessionId]` variables. So I've added a `sessionId` to each request and then each script uses it. It works great without the `sessionId` and doesn't work as I expect with. I'm having a hard time understanding why. This is a sample code to demonstrate my problem:

```
session_start();
$sessionId = $_REQUEST['sessionId']; 

if ($_REQUEST['currId'] == 0) {
    unset ($_SESSION[$sessionId]);
    $_SESSION[$sessionId]['log'] = "starting log for session " . $s;
}

if ($_REQUEST['currId'] < $_REQUEST['limit']) {
    $_SESSION[$sessionId]['log'] .= " adding ";

    // call with next currId
    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="1;URL=' . "'test3.php?limit=" . $_REQUEST['limit'] . "&currId=" . ($_REQUEST['currId']+1) . "&sessionId=" . $sessionId . "'" . '">';
}

// reached limit
else {
    echo $_SESSION[$sessionId]['log'];
};
```

I'm invoking first a call to `test3.php?limit=5&currId=0&sessionId=0` and than expect the code to re-call itself with currId=1,2,3,4,5. This is happening Ok. but the $_SESSION isn't kept as I 
expect it to be. When I remove the `sessionId` usage, it does work.  But that way I can only invoke one crawler simultaneously unless I open a different browser...

Thanks

Comment: I 'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish here. If `test3.php` is somehow responsible for launching server-side workers, then have it launch all of them at once. As for having the browser window do some work, it's obvious that if you keep redirecting it it's only going to be able to do one thing at a time anyway.

Comment: Because the number of server-side workers is huge, I would like it to do one worker at a time. This way I can stop it whenever I want, and than continue. This is why I'm saving the data of the "what work needs to be done" in the $_SESSION. Now this is working great, I just wanted to add an option to run a couple of these workers managers together which share the same $_SESSION.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have more luck with a `sessionId` that isn't a number. If you turn error reporting up with [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)`(E_ALL)`; you'll see some notices, one of which is `Notice: Unknown: Skipping numeric key 0 in Unknown on line 0`.

According to one commenter on the [php pages](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php) this is caused by using an integer as a key for the `$_SESSION` array - when I tried this without the error disappears.

You have also got a variable `$s` in there, which I assume should be `$sessionId`, that'd give a notice too.

Comment: It was exactly this. When I didn't use a numeric value it worked! Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I've never come across this before either - I wonder why it doesn't like it